# How to make the drop down menu responsive?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive

is there anyone who's able to make this drop down menu responsive ?
the problem I have is that when I resize the browser the boxes float left

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>CSS3 animated & responsive dropdown menu</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <nav class="animenu"> 
 <button class="animenu__toggle">
   <span class="animenu__toggle__bar"></span>
   <span class="animenu__toggle__bar"></span>
   <span class="animenu__toggle__bar"></span>
</button>
 <ul class="animenu__nav">
   <li>
     <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Archive</a>
     <ul class="animenu__nav__child">
       <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>     
   <li>
     <a href="#">Categories</a>
     <ul class="animenu__nav__child">
       <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>       
    <li>
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
   </li> 
    <li>
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li> 

  </ul>
</nav>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.animenu__toggle {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
.animenu__toggle:hover {
  background-color: #0186ba;
}

.animenu__toggle__bar {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.75, -0.55, 0.25, 1.55);
}
.animenu__toggle__bar + .animenu__toggle__bar {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.animenu__toggle--active .animenu__toggle__bar {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.animenu__toggle--active .animenu__toggle__bar:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.animenu__toggle--active .animenu__toggle__bar:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.animenu__toggle--active .animenu__toggle__bar:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.animenu {
  display: block;
}
.animenu ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font: 0px 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica;
}
.animenu li, .animenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.animenu a {
 color: #aaaaaa;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.animenu__nav {
  background-color: #111;
}
.animenu__nav > li {
  position: relative;
  border-right: 1px solid #444444;
}
.animenu__nav > li > a {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.animenu__nav > li > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 border: 4px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 0;
  border-top-color: currentColor;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
  right: 10px;
}
.animenu__nav > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
}
.animenu__nav > li:hover > a {
color: #fff;
}

.animenu__nav__child {
 min-width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 margin: 20px 0 0 0;
 background-color: #373737;
 transition: margin .15s, opacity .15s;
}
.animenu__nav__child > li {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #515151;
}
.animenu__nav__child > li:first-child > a:after {
  content: '';
 position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: 1em;
 top: -6px;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom-color: inherit;
    }
.animenu__nav__child > li:last-child {
  border: 0;
}
.animenu__nav__child a {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: #373737;
}
.animenu__nav__child a:hover {
  background-color: #0186ba;
  border-color: #0186ba;
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .animenu__toggle {
   display: inline-block;
 }

  .animenu__nav,
  .animenu__nav__child {
    display: none;
}

.animenu__nav {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.animenu__nav > li {
  width: 100%;
   border-right: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #515151;
 }
 .animenu__nav > li:last-child {
   border: 0;
 }
 .animenu__nav > li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left: 1em;
    top: -6px;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom-color: inherit;
  }
.animenu__nav > li > a {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px;
   border-color: #111;
   position: relative;
 }
 .animenu__nav a:hover {
   background-color: #0186ba;
   border-color: #0186ba;
   color: #fff;
 }

 .animenu__nav__child {
   position: static;
   background-color: #373737;
   margin: 0;
   transition: none;
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
 }
  .animenu__nav__child > li:first-child > a:after {
    content: none;
 }
  .animenu__nav__child a {
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.animenu__nav--open {
  display: block !important;
}
.animenu__nav--open .animenu__nav__child {
display: block;
}
```

**SCSS**

```
// Variables
$baseMenuBackground: #111;          // Base color theme
$secondaryMenuBackground: #0186ba;  // Secondary color (highlights, triangles...)
$gutter: 10px;                      // Base gutter

// Latest CSS box model 
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

// The classic hamburger icon
// <button class="animenu__toggle">
//   <span class="animenu__toggle__bar"></span>
//   <span class="animenu__toggle__bar"></span>
//   <span class="animenu__toggle__bar"></span>
// </button>
.animenu__toggle {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: $baseMenuBackground;
  border: 0; 
  padding: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;

  &:hover {
    background-color: $secondaryMenuBackground;
  }
}

.animenu__toggle__bar {
  display: block;
  width: 20px; height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;    
  transition: .15s cubic-bezier(0.75, -0.55, 0.25, 1.55);

  &+.animenu__toggle__bar {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }  
}

.animenu__toggle--active {
  .animenu__toggle__bar {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;

    &:nth-child(1) {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }        
  }
}

// Clear some defaults
.animenu {
  display: block;
  ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;    
    font: 0px 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica;    
  }

  li, a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  a {
    color: lighten($baseMenuBackground, 60%);
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

// First level -> main menu items
// <nav class="animenu">
//    <ul class="animenu__nav">
//    ...
//    </ul>
//  </nav>
.animenu__nav {
  background-color: $baseMenuBackground;        

 > li {
   position: relative;
   border-right: 1px solid lighten($baseMenuBackground, 20%);

    > a {
      padding: $gutter 3 * $gutter;
      text-transform: uppercase;

      &:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before { 
       content:""; 
       position: absolute;
       border: 4px solid transparent;
       border-bottom: 0; 
       border-top-color: currentColor;
       top: 50%;
       margin-top: -2px;
       right: 10px;  
      }  
    }    

   &:hover {
     > ul {
       opacity: 1;
       visibility: visible;
       margin: 0;        
     }

     > a {
       color: #fff;
     }
   }
 }
}

// Second level
// <nav class="animenu">
//    <ul class="animenu__nav">
//      <li>
//        <ul class="animenu__nav__child"></ul>
//      </li>
//    </ul>
//  </nav>
.animenu__nav__child {
  min-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; left: 0;
  z-index: 1;   
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 2 * $gutter 0 0 0;
  background-color: lighten($baseMenuBackground, 15%);    
  transition: margin .15s, opacity .15s;

  > li {
   width: 100%;
   border-bottom: 1px solid lighten($baseMenuBackground, 25%);

   &:first-child > a:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     height: 0; width: 0;
     left: 1em;
     top: -6px;
     border: 6px solid transparent;
     border-top: 0;
     border-bottom-color: inherit;
   }

    &:last-child {
      border: 0;
    }
  }

  a {
   padding: $gutter;
   width: 100%;
   border-color: lighten($baseMenuBackground, 15%);

   &:hover {
     background-color: $secondaryMenuBackground;
     border-color: $secondaryMenuBackground;
     color: #fff;
   }
  }
}

// The main breakpoint is 767px
// Adjust the first and second levels display
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .animenu__toggle {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .animenu__nav,
  .animenu__nav__child {
    display: none;
  }

// First level -> main menu items
// <nav class="animenu">
//    <ul class="animenu__nav">
//    ...
//    </ul>
//  </nav>    
 .animenu__nav {
   margin: $gutter 0;

   > li {
     width: 100%;
     border-right: 0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid lighten($baseMenuBackground, 25%);

    &:last-child {
    border: 0; 
     }

     &:first-child > a:after {
       content: '';
       position: absolute;
       height: 0; width: 0;
       left: 1em;
       top: -6px;
       border: 6px solid transparent;
       border-top: 0;
        border-bottom-color: inherit;
      }

     > a {
       width: 100%;
       padding: $gutter;
       border-color: $baseMenuBackground;
       position: relative; //dropdown caret
     }
   }

    a:hover {
     background-color: $secondaryMenuBackground;
     border-color: $secondaryMenuBackground;
     color: #fff;      
   }
 }

 // Second level
// <nav class="animenu">
//    <ul class="animenu__nav">
//      <li>
//        <ul class="animenu__nav__child"></ul>
//      </li>
//    </ul>
//  </nav>              
 .animenu__nav__child {
    position: static;
    background-color: lighten($baseMenuBackground, 15%);
    margin: 0;
    transition: none;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;     

    > li:first-child > a:after {
      content: none;
    }

   a {
     padding-left: 2 * $gutter;
     width: 100%;
    }           
  }
}

// Expanding the animenu
// <nav class="animenu">
//    <ul class="animenu__nav animenu__nav--open">
//      <li>
//        <ul class="animenu__nav__child"></ul>
//      </li>
//    </ul>
//  </nav>
.animenu__nav--open {
  display: block !important;

  & .animenu__nav__child {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

**.JS**

```
    // CSS3 animated & responsive dropdown menu
// Latest version: https://github.com/catalinred/Animenu

(function(){
    var animenuToggle = document.querySelector('.animenu__toggle'),
        animenuNav    = document.querySelector('.animenu__nav'),
        hasClass = function( elem, className ) {
            return new RegExp( ' ' + className + ' ' ).test( ' ' + elem.className + ' ' );
        },
        toggleClass = function( elem, className ) {
            var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace( /[\t\r\n]/g, ' ' ) + ' ';
            if( hasClass(elem, className ) ) {
                while( newClass.indexOf( ' ' + className + ' ' ) >= 0 ) {
                    newClass = newClass.replace( ' ' + className + ' ' , ' ' );
                }
                elem.className = newClass.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g, '' );
            } else {
                elem.className += ' ' + className;
            }
        },           
        animenuToggleNav =  function (){        
            toggleClass(animenuToggle, "animenu__toggle--active");
            toggleClass(animenuNav, "animenu__nav--open");        
        }

if (!animenuToggle.addEventListener) {
    animenuToggle.attachEvent("onclick", animenuToggleNav);
}
    else {
        animenuToggle.addEventListener('click', animenuToggleNav);
    }
})()
```

Any help would be appreciated, THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Basically, this is what happens if i resize the page.

Comment: What isn't responsive about it? Does [this Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/40rwzts9/show/light/) not have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, it does. the thing I don't understand is why when I resize the page the box contact goes underneath the logo button and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <style>
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #660033;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 10px 54px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #660033;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 17.5px;
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background: #3db2e1;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px #209ed0, inset 0 2px 1px #7fcceb;
  background-size: 36px 36px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:after {
  background-position: 0 -18px;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 11px;
  top: 25.5px;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 99;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  border-top-color: #19799f;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: top .2s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: top .2s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  -o-transition: top .2s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  transition: top .2s ease, opacity .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  top: 91px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  top: 51px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 40px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 178px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 178px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 12px 25px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #3db2e1;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li > a:hover,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #88d0ed;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 #27a9de, inset 0 -3px 3px #1f9acc, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: 12px;
  top: 9.5px;
  background: #3db2e1;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px #209ed0, inset 0 2px 1px #7fcceb;
  background-size: 36px 36px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 12px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:after {
  background-position: 0 -18px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  top: 15.5px;
  right: 16px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  top: 15.5px;
  right: auto;
  left: 16px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #1c89b5;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #1c89b5;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul,
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul,
  #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul li:hover > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: none;
    background: #660033;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    padding-left: 12.5px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding: 14px 25px 14px 27.5px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 42.5px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 57.5px;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 12.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #660033;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 53px;
    height: 53px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
    height: 41px;
  }

  #cssmenu ul .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after,
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
    background-position: 0 -28px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
    top: 6.5px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before,
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 22.5px;
    top: 25.5px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
    top: 19.5px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before,
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
    border-top-color: #19799f;
  }
}

   </style>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
        (function($) {

          $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {

              var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
                title: "&#9776;",
                format: "dropdown",
                sticky: false
              }, options);

              return this.each(function() {
                cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button" class="icon">' + settings.title + '</div>');
                $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
                  $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
                  var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
                  if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
                    mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
                  }
                  else {
                    mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
                    if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                      mainmenu.find('ul').show();
                    }
                  }
                });

                cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

                multiTg = function() {
                  cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
                  cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
                    $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
                    if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                      $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
                    }
                    else {
                      $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
                    }
                  });
                };

                if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
                else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

                if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

                resizeFix = function() {
                  if ($( window ).width() > 768) {
                    cssmenu.find('ul').show();
                  }

                  if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
                    cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
                  }
                };
                resizeFix();
                return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

              });
          };
        })(jQuery);

        (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
           title: "&#9776;",
           format: "multitoggle"
        });


        });
        })(jQuery);
   </script>
   <title>Resposnive menu</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```